# Change the display text in a Tkinter label widget based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The code below is what I'm referencing
    from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()

#Variables
answer = "Enter Answer"

data = ""

#Functions
def function():
    data = e.get()
    while data == "":
        if data == 5:
            answer = "Correct"
        if data != 5:
            answer = "Incorrect"
    print(answer)


top = Label(root, text = "Test")
top.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = Button(root, text = "Enter", command = function)
b.pack()

check = Label(root, text = answer)
check.pack()

mainloop()
```

I can't seem to update the label widget (name 'check').
I want to be able to update it based checking a condition, but I can't get it to work.
I placed the 'print(answer)' line to check the variable, but I get the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:/Portable Apps/Portable Python 3.2.5.1/Documents/TEST.py", line 22, in function
    print(answer)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'answer' referenced before assignment
```

This occurs when I run the program, type a value, then select the enter button.

Answer (score 1):

Your `answer` variable is not defined within the function's scope. To accomplish this in the simplest way I suggest you use a class to hold all of the widgets from your UI.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window():

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.top = Label(root, text = "Test")
        self.top.pack()

        self.e = Entry(root)
        self.e.pack()
        self.e.focus_set()

        self.b = Button(root, text = "Enter", command = self.function)
        self.b.pack()

        self.answer = StringVar()
        self.answer.set("Enter answer")

        self.check = Label(root, text = self.answer.get(), textvariable = self.answer)
        self.check.pack()

    #Functions
    def function(self):

        data = self.e.get()

        if data == "5":
            self.answer.set("Correct")
        else:
            self.answer.set("Incorrect")

root = Tk()
w = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Additionally, since widget `command`'s work as callbacks, you won't need to use a while loop to accomplish what you want. Just put the if/else check, as I have done, and every time you click the button it will check again.

I also changed your `answer` variable to be an instance of `StringVar()`. This is a type of Tkinter variable specifically designed to accomplish what you're trying to do. I can then use the config option `textvariable = self.answer` to allow the label to update whenever the `StringVar` is changed. To access the text of the StringVar you must call `self.answer.get()`; to change the data you call `self.answer.set("text")` like I have done within `function`.

Finally, since your `Entry` `self.e` is an instance of `StringVar` as well, I had to change your `if` condition to `if data == "5":` as data will be a String rather than an int.